# My second data science project: Classifying the price at fine art auctions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, feature-engineering, keras

This is my second data science project and i am looking for insights from people more experienced than me. I am completely self-taught and new to this and would appreciate any kind of feedback.

The first project I did was about predicting which artist had painted a painting. This new project is something different, its tabular data and the first was images.

I am trying to predict the price at fine art auctions.

I am classifying the price as unsold, below the auction house price range, in the range, or above the range.

---

I have scraped the data from swedish auction houses.

The data is made up of

- The price
- The title of the art work
- A description of the art work
- The name of the artist
- The auction house estimated price range
- Artist's country
- Artist's lifetime
- The Provenance (i.e. information about who as owned the painting earlier and such things)
- Exhibition information

After cleaning the data and keeping only those records where the artist.value_counts >= 15, i.e. the artist have had at least 15 items at auction, i end up with about in total 12.000 items sold.

Investigating the data, these are the features i find:

String categorical features

- artist name
- artist country
- the currency of the sold item

Integer categorical features

- exh (Exhibited or not)
- prov (Provenance or not)
- desc (Description or not)
- tit (Title or not)
- signed (Whether the painting is signed or not)
- dated (Whether the painting is dated)
- dyear (If its dated, what year)
- w_in_title (If the title contains words like summer, winter, girl or stockholm)
- medium (If its a oil painting, drawing, gouach, etching, lithograph etc)

Numerical features

- birth year
- death year
- low (The low end of the auction house estimated price)
- high (The high end of the auction house estimated price)

---

Correlation matrix:

[image]
I remove desc and low.

Are the correlations with price too low?

---

Then on the numerical features I perform a power transformation to make the data more gaussian like, a quantile transformation - spreading out the most frequent values and reducing the impact of outliers and finally i remove the mean and scale it to unit variance.

---

Then some tensorflow preprocessing layers

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import Normalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import CategoryEncoding
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import StringLookup


def encode_numerical_feature(feature, name, dataset):
    # Create a Normalization layer for our feature
    normalizer = Normalization()

    # Prepare a Dataset that only yields our feature
    feature_ds = dataset.map(lambda x, y: x[name])
    feature_ds = feature_ds.map(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, -1))

    # Learn the statistics of the data
    normalizer.adapt(feature_ds)

    # Normalize the input feature
    encoded_feature = normalizer(feature)
    return encoded_feature


def encode_string_categorical_feature(feature, name, dataset):
    # Create a StringLookup layer which will turn strings into integer indices
    index = StringLookup()

    # Prepare a Dataset that only yields our feature
    feature_ds = dataset.map(lambda x, y: x[name])
    feature_ds = feature_ds.map(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, -1))

    # Learn the set of possible string values and assign them a fixed integer index
    index.adapt(feature_ds)

    # Turn the string input into integer indices
    encoded_feature = index(feature)

    # Create a CategoryEncoding for our integer indices
    encoder = CategoryEncoding(output_mode="binary")

    # Prepare a dataset of indices
    feature_ds = feature_ds.map(index)

    # Learn the space of possible indices
    encoder.adapt(feature_ds)

    # Apply one-hot encoding to our indices
    encoded_feature = encoder(encoded_feature)
    return encoded_feature


def encode_integer_categorical_feature(feature, name, dataset):
    # Create a CategoryEncoding for our integer indices
    encoder = CategoryEncoding(output_mode="binary")

    # Prepare a Dataset that only yields our feature
    feature_ds = dataset.map(lambda x, y: x[name])
    feature_ds = feature_ds.map(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, -1))

    # Learn the space of possible indices
    encoder.adapt(feature_ds)

    # Apply one-hot encoding to our indices
    encoded_feature = encoder(feature)
    return encoded_feature
```

---

Then I build a keras model, after some trial and error, and run keras tuner to tune the hyperparameters.

```py
hp = HyperParameters()

def model_builder(hp):
  
  x = Dense(units=256, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.L2(l2=0.01), 
          kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.HeNormal(), kernel_constraint=keras.constraints.UnitNorm(axis=0), 
          name = "Dense1")(all_features)
  x = PReLU()(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)
  x = Dropout(rate=hp.Float('dropout1',
              min_value=0.0,
              max_value=0.2,
              default=0,
              step=0.02))(x)
  x = Dense(units=hp.Int('units2', 0, 128, step=16), kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.L2(l2=0.01), 
          kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.HeNormal(), kernel_constraint=keras.constraints.UnitNorm(axis=0), 
          name = "Dense2")(x)
  x = PReLU()(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)
  x = Dropout(rate=hp.Float('dropout2',
              min_value=0.0,
              max_value=0.2,
              default=0,
              step=0.02))(x)
  x = Dense(units=hp.Int('units3', 0, 128, step=16), kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.L2(l2=0.01), 
          kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.HeNormal(), kernel_constraint=keras.constraints.UnitNorm(axis=0), 
          name = "Dense3")(x)
  x = PReLU()(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)
  x = Dropout(rate=hp.Float('dropout3',
              min_value=0.0,
              max_value=0.2,
              default=0,
              step=0.02))(x)
  x = Dense(units=hp.Int('units4', 0, 64, step=8), kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.L2(l2=0.01), 
          kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.HeNormal(), kernel_constraint=keras.constraints.UnitNorm(axis=0), 
          name = "Dense4")(x)
  x = PReLU()(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)
  x = Dropout(rate=hp.Float('dropout4',
              min_value=0.0,
              max_value=0.2,
              default=0,
              step=0.02))(x)
  x = Dense(units=hp.Int('units5', 0, 32, step=4), kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.L2(l2=0.01), 
          kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.HeNormal(), kernel_constraint=keras.constraints.UnitNorm(axis=0), 
          name = "Dense5")(x)
  x = PReLU()(x)
  x = BatchNormalization()(x)
  x = Dropout(rate=hp.Float('dropout5',
              min_value=0.0,
              max_value=0.2,
              default=0,
              step=0.02))(x)
 
  output = Dense(4, activation="softmax", name = "Outputlayer")(x)

  model = keras.Model(all_inputs, output)


  model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
                hp.Choice('learning_rate',
                values=[1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-3])),
                loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  return model
```

A view of the model:

[image]

```py
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('./checkpoints9/best_weights.tf', monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=10, verbose=1, min_delta=1e-4, mode='min')
earlyStopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=30, verbose=0, mode='min')
```

```py
tuner = BayesianOptimization(
    model_builder,
    max_trials=200,
    executions_per_trial=2,
    hyperparameters=hp,
    tune_new_entries=True,
    allow_new_entries=True,
    beta = 4,
    seed = 323,
    directory = "/content/drive/MyDrive/output",
    project_name = "Auction",
    objective='val_accuracy')

tuner.search(train_ds,
             validation_data=val_ds,
             verbose=1,
             epochs = 100,
             callbacks = [checkpoint, reduce_lr, earlyStopping])
```

---

Training one of the "best" models.

```py
Epoch 1/300
244/244 [==============================] - 7s 14ms/step - 
loss: 6.3068 - accuracy: 0.3475 - val_loss: 6.1117 - val_accuracy: 0.3175
```

It improves slightly

```py
Epoch 35/300
244/244 [==============================] - 3s 11ms/step - 
loss: 6.0440 - accuracy: 0.4093 - val_loss: 6.0420 - val_accuracy: 0.4054
```

```py
Epoch 300/300
244/244 [==============================] - 3s 11ms/step - 
loss: 5.9001 - accuracy: 0.5058 - val_loss: 6.0521 - val_accuracy: 0.4117

Epoch 00300: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.42556
```

---

Confusion matrix:

[image]

---

So obviously it is awful.

Any ideas on what I can improve?

I am new to this so any comment, critique or suggestion you may have, however small, I am interested to hear about it.

(If you want me to add anything to the above, let me know.)

Comment: Could you turn it into question? Q&A site is not the best platform for open-ended discussion.

Comment: You mean a more specific question than "What can I improve?"? Do you know a better place for me post this question?

Comment: I agree this isn’t the site for generic “what can I improve” but I will add that removing features based on correlation before doing any sort of cross validation could lead to some issues with overfitting

Comment: @Tim and others - I looked around yesterday for where to post this and ended up here. If you can recommend a better place for this post i would appreciate it.